# How to create arrow in between a line segment in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, line

I have a `ggplot` plot with four line segments and I want to add an arrow in between one of the segments. Here is my code:

```r
plot <- ggplot(combined_total_active_2, aes(x = 0, y = 0)) +
  coord_fixed()+ 
  theme_void()+ 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))

plot <- plot + with_outer_glow(geom_segment(aes(x = -3, y = 0, xend = 3, yend = 0), color = "#dd7733",size = 1.5, 
            lineend = "round"),colour="#ffc559", sigma=4,expand=1) + 
  with_outer_glow(geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = -3, xend = 0, yend = 3), color = "#dd7733",size = 1.5, 
            lineend = "round"),colour="#ffc559", sigma=4,expand=1, arrow = arrow())

plot <- plot + geom_point(aes(x = -3, y = 0), size = 50, shape = 21,
                          fill = "#11141a", color = "#ffc559", stroke = 2) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = 3, y = 0), size = 50, shape = 21, fill = "#11141a", color = "#ffc559", stroke = 2) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = -3), size = 50, shape = 21, fill = "#11141a", color = "#ffc559", stroke = 2) +  
  geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = 3), size = 50, shape = 21, fill = "#11141a", color = "#ffc559", stroke = 2)+ 
  geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = 0), size = 30, shape = 21, fill = "#11141a", color = "#ffc559", stroke = 2)

plot <- plot + xlim(-4, 4) + ylim(-4, 4)

plot
```

Output:

[image]

How can I add an arrow in between the two circles or something like this?

[image]